# 'Provider' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its instance type 'Provider<AnyAction>' is not a valid JSX element. TS2786

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Makes the Redux store available to the connect() calls in the component hierarchy below.

'Provider' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its instance type 'Provider' is not a valid JSX element.
The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("C:/Users/Nilay/Desktop/nilay/src/pages/Home/Reel/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2786)

can anyone can tell how to fix this i have tried npm install again my node version is 18plus

[img here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQSKk.png)

```
    import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { store } from "./app/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
import { apolloClient } from "./utils/index";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <App />
        </Provider>
      </ApolloProvider>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: @Spectric tell how to fix this check my code

Answer (score 2):

It seems like @types/react problem with multiple versions.
Try to uninstall react-redux and react (check that the dependencies removed) and install again.

Also try to install @types/react, its installed through dependencies.

Some workarounds can be found here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24304#issuecomment-1094565891